# What Javascript Event causes an input with a list attribute to render its list?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an input element like so:

```
<input list='foo'>
<datalist id = 'foo'>some options</datalist>
```

Is it possible to use javascript events in order to delay rendering the list until x number of characters have been entered and other fine tuning things like that?

I cannot seem to prevent this list from popping up. I have found documentation on the native behavior, but unfortunately I have been unable to find anything on this specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I think you're going to be able to do, without writing your own custom component, is attributing and de-attributing the list depending on the length of the value in the input.

This gives mixed results though.  Sometimes you have to de-focus and re-focus the input after the list has been attributed to have it start showing up.  Firefox behaves this way, but Chrome will react whether you have focused the `<input>` or not.

[image: Chrome Behaviour]

```js
const foo = document.getElementById("foo");

foo.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const hasList = foo.hasAttribute("list");
  const shouldHaveList = foo.value.length > 2;

  if (shouldHaveList && !hasList) foo.setAttribute("list", "list");
  if (!shouldHaveList && hasList) foo.removeAttribute("list");

});
```

```html
<input id="foo">
<datalist id="list">
  <option value="bobby">
  <option value="sharron">
  <option value="susan">
  <option value="michael">
  <option value="gregory">
  <option value="steve">
</datalist>
```